# How to fetch MySQL data in PHP table?

Tags: php

I want to fetch some records from MySQL view table in my web page by PHP. I am using this following code:

```
 $result="SELECT method,test_name,test_code FROM vtest_ord ORDER BY
 test_ord_id DESC"; 
 echo"<table border='1'><thead><tr><th>Method</th><th>Test Name</th><th>Test
 Code</th></tr></thead>"; 
 while ($row=$mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
 echo "<tr><td>";    
 echo "<td>" . $row['method'] . "</td>";   
 echo "<td>" . $row['test_name'] . "</td>";   
 echo "<td>" .
 $row['test_code'] . "</td>";   
 echo "</tr></td>"; }
 echo '</table>';
```

but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\ord_view.php on line 211 Method Test Name   Test
>   Code (table header shows)

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` and not `$mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: can you tell which is  211  number line in your ord_view.php?

Answer (score 1):

You need basic php logic. you have some serious errors in your code. please try to read basic of programming.

**some errors:**
1) `$mysql_fetch_assoc` is not a variable it is a function `mysql_fetch_assoc();` you can not use $ in this name.

2) you need to execute query first then you can fetch.

```
 $link = mysql_connect('host_name','db_user_name','db_password'); //fill correct credentials
 mysql_select_db('your_db_name'); //set your database name
 $sql="SELECT method,test_name,test_code FROM vtest_ord ORDER BY
 test_ord_id DESC"; 
 echo"<table border='1'><thead><tr><th>Method</th><th>Test Name</th><th>Test
 Code</th></tr></thead>"; 
 $result =  mysql_query($sql);  // execute query
 while ($row=$mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
 echo "<tr><td>";    
 echo "<td>" . $row['method'] . "</td>";   
 echo "<td>" . $row['test_name'] . "</td>";   
 echo "<td>" .
 $row['test_code'] . "</td>";   
 echo "</tr></td>"; }
 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: does not work. same error. Thanks.

Comment: I think this one is potential to solve my issue. I used all you suggests with "while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))" and I got error " No database selected
Method Test Name Test Code (table header)". Could you please help me more little. Thanks.

Comment: sure :)  you should check your database connection. try my updated answer and let me know

Comment: I used "include/dbcon.php" which is ok I beleive as it works for other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problem with the PHP syntax.

- `mysql_fetch_assoc` is a function and you called it like a variable (which means nothing here).
- You try to call this function with a string, but you need a ressource, obtain via `mysql_query`.
- You don't need to write multiple `echo` statement, thanks to the concatenation syntax.

A potential correct code is:

```
  $sql="SELECT method, test_name, test_code FROM vtest_ord ORDER BY test_ord_id DESC";  
  echo "[Debug] MethodTest NameTest Code"; 
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); // Display SQL error if raised
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row['method'] . " " . $row['test_name'] . " " . $row['test_code']; echo ""; 
  }
```

I also advise you to drop `mysql_*` and use [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php), since the first one is deprecated for years now.

Comment: doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I just used your code without using PDO. I am not familiar with PDO. But it gave me debug error as well as same error msg as I mentioned earlier. Thanks for your help. Please give me some thing different with out PDO. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this file? Have you correctly replace the portion of code? Refreshing cache/server/whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You need execute the query using `mysql_query`, **Also, `mysql_fetch_assoc` not a `$mysql_fetch_assoc` function**

```
  $query ="SELECT method,test_name,test_code FROM vtest_ord ORDER BY test_ord_id DESC"; 
  $result =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Should be

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

instead of

```
while ($row=$mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

**Note:** Use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

**Here you can find good tutorial for connecting mysql database:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: does not work but change error into "No database selected". Thanks.

Comment: I have added ref link for connecting db and it tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `mysql_query` method.

Then you could use the returned resource with the `mysql_fetch_assoc` function in which you have a typo. You're treating it as a variable and not a function.